# function within a function in c

Tags: c

In the function doubleadd i want the result as the summation of x and function add

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a,int b)
{ return (a+b); }

int doubleadd(int x,int y=(*add)(int a,int b))
{ return (x+y); }

void main()
{
    void (*ptr)(int,int);
    ptr=add;
    int y=ptr(5,7);
    printf("%d",y);
    y=doubleadd(3,ptr(5,7));
}
```

please help me with this problem

Comment: And where do you place mine? :P

Comment: It is unclear what you want, and even more why you would want anything like this.

Comment: Oh, didn't even see that. Even faster than Neil :)

Comment: @bajaj: That's certainly an attempt at *functional* C, I think you will find this isn't a viable approach.

Comment: I don't see why the close votes - this is an answerable question, the OP simply doesn't know the correct syntax.

Comment: why don't you provide the mathematical representation of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do all that mess! This will be fine:

```
y = doubleadd(3, add(5,7));
```

and the prototype of doubleadd is

```
int doubleadd(int x, int y) { ... }
```

you can pass complex expressions as parameters, too

Answer (score 1):

In the unlikely event you want to turn your C code into some bastard child of a functional language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*addfun)( int a, int b );

int add(int a,int b) { 
    return a + b; 
}

int doubleadd(int x, addfun f, int a, int b ) { 
    return x + f( a, b ); 
}

int main() {
    addfun fn = add;
    int y = doubleadd(3, fn,  5, 7 );
    printf( "%d\n", y );
}
```